# How to log into one aws cloudwatch stream from multiple beanstalk application instances

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have AWS Beanstalk application with 2 instances. Each instance creates it's own log stream in CloudWatch.

Each instance is a host of .NET Core application with AWS.Logger.AspNetCore nuget package.
appsettings section:

```
  "Logging": {
    "Region": "eu-central-1",
    "LogGroup": "MyLogGroup",
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
```

Is there any way to log all instances to single commong log stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html)

> a log stream is a sequence of events that share the same source.

This basically means that each instance created by your Elastic Beanstalk environment will send events to separate log streams because, even though they are the same application, they are technically different event sources. The same applies to other AWS services, most notably Lambda where you could have 1000 instances of the same function running concurrently; each one will produce its own log stream.

If you’re searching for something specific using the console, there’s an option at the root of a log group labelled `Search Log Group`, which will allow you to search all the log streams in a log group using the console.

For CLI based search you can use the AWS CLI, although, we have found this cumbersome in our environment. There are many commercial and open source solutions for log aggregation, processing, and analytics.For us, we have had success using the open source [AWS Cloudwatch Logs For Humans](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs/) which allows you to “aggregate and query logs across multiple streams in pseudo-realtime”.